# Vector/array output from `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`

Tags: python, scipy

Basically, is it possible to get `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` to return a multi-valued structure, instead of just a scalar? I'd like to be able to interpolate once to retrieve 5 values at a point, rather than having to interpolate 5 times.

Here's my try at a MWE to demonstrate the problem. I'll start with a 3D interpolation of a scalar. I won't go between points for now because that's not the point.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
coords = np.array([[1.,1.,1.]])
a = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape(3,3,3)
ndimage.map_coordinates(a,coords.T) # array([13.])
```

Now, suppose I want `a` to have pairs of values, not just one. My instinct is

```
a = np.arange(3*3*3*2).reshape(3,3,3,2)
a[1,1,1] # array([26.,27.])
ndimage.map_coordinates(a[:,:,:],coords.T)  # I'd like array([26.,27.])
```

Instead of the desired output, I get the following:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)/<ipython-input-84-77334fb7469f> in <module>()
----> 1 ndimage.map_coordinates(a[:,:,:],np.array([[1.,1.,1.]]).T)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/interpolation.pyc in map_coordinates(input, coordinates, output, order, mode, cval, prefilter)
    287         raise RuntimeError('input and output rank must be > 0')
    288     if coordinates.shape[0] != input.ndim:
--> 289         raise RuntimeError('invalid shape for coordinate array')
    290     mode = _extend_mode_to_code(mode)
    291     if prefilter and order > 1:

RuntimeError: invalid shape for coordinate array
```

I can't find a permutation of the shapes of any of the structures (`a`, `coords`, etc.) that gives me the answer I'm looking for. Also, if there's a better way to do this than using `map_coordinates`, go ahead. I thought `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` might be the way to go but I can't find any documentation or an inkling of what it might do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible, I think.

But tensor product interpolation is not difficult:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def interpn(*args, **kw):
    """Interpolation on N-D. 

    ai = interpn(x, y, z, ..., a, xi, yi, zi, ...)
    where the arrays x, y, z, ... define a rectangular grid
    and a.shape == (len(x), len(y), len(z), ...)
    """
    method = kw.pop('method', 'cubic')
    if kw:
        raise ValueError("Unknown arguments: " % kw.keys())
    nd = (len(args)-1)//2
    if len(args) != 2*nd+1:
        raise ValueError("Wrong number of arguments")
    q = args[:nd]
    qi = args[nd+1:]
    a = args[nd]
    for j in range(nd):
        a = interp1d(q[j], a, axis=j, kind=method)(qi[j])
    return a

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 6)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 7)
k = np.array([0, 1])
z = np.cos(2*x[:,None,None] + k[None,None,:]) * np.sin(3*y[None,:,None])

xi = np.linspace(0, 1, 60)
yi = np.linspace(0, 1, 70)
zi = interpn(x, y, z, xi, yi, method='linear')

plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(z[:,:,0].T, interpolation='nearest')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(zi[:,:,0].T, interpolation='nearest')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(z[:,:,1].T, interpolation='nearest')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(zi[:,:,1].T, interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. Unfortunately, the main reason I started using `map_coordinates` is because it scales well into large datasets. At the moment, my experimental grid is 488x101x3, but it'll grow to at least 488x101x11x6x7, in which case this method seems to be really slow. Unless it can be turned into some kind of interpolator object or something?

Comment: `map_coordinates` probably derives its speed partly from the fact that its grid is uniformly spaced, which makes interpolation cheaper. Another issue here is that if you want to evaluate the function at single scattered points, rather than on a new grid, the iterated interp1d solution won't cut it, as it essentially recomputes the spline coefficients each time it's called. Tensor product splines (which the iterated interp1d is an instance of) can be precomputed, evaluating is AFAIK not difficult, but I'm not aware of existing N-d implementations for Python (apart from `map_coordinates`).